# Get error 400 when request made through python requests, but works in cURL

Tags: python, curl, hashicorp-vault

This issue has quite a few entries out there, but after scanning them, seeing what they offered, and trying it out on the code that I'm working with, and having no luck, figured I'd add my problem to the pile. Here's the code that I am working with.

```
import json
import requests

token = "ABC"
ip_address = "1.1.1.1"

url     = "http://" + ip_address + ":8200/v1/kv/test-secret"
payload = {"key":"value"}
headers = {'X-Vault-Token': token}

res = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)

print(res.status_code, res.reason)
```

This code will always return error 400 Bad Request. Have done the low hanging fruit of verifying the token, url, that the request config for POST is correct, that sort of thing (the token and ip isn't correct, for obvious reasons)

Meanwhile, this works fine.

```
curl --header "X-Vault-Token: ABC" --request POST --data @payload.json http://1.1.1.1/v1/secret/data/my-secret
```

If anyone has any ideas, I'm all ears. I'll freely admit I am not a python expert so I'm betting money I've done something wrong there. I just can't see what it is.

Comment: Those are very different URLs.

Answer (score 0):

Had exactly the same issue. The issue was after alot of messing around was to change the requests to a get:

```
import json
import requests

token = "ABC"
ip_address = "1.1.1.1"

url     = "http://" + ip_address + ":8200/v1/kv/test-secret"
payload = {"key":"value"}
headers = {"X-Vault-Token": "token"}

res = requests.get(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)

print(res.status_code, res.reason)
```

That fixed the issue for me. Feel your pain though, shame the docs aren't more clear.

If you are using are more up to date version of Vault, you may want to look at the hvac library and using approle to authenticate: [LINK](https://hvac.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage/auth_methods/approle.html#authentication)

Then use the secrets engine to get the values from vault.